# Time Complexity of Split AVL Tree Function

Tags: c, insert, time-complexity, complexity-theory, avl-tree

I have the following code for splitting the AVL tree and I'm not quite sure if it has Time Complexity of **O(log(n))** or **O((log n)<sup>2</sup>)**.

**Note:**

- The Complexity of **`join`** is **O(log(n))** where `n` is the `Number of Elements in Two Trees combined`
- Complexity of **`insert`** is also **O(log(n))** where `n` is the `Number of Elements in the Tree`.

```c
    node* split(node* t, int k)
    {  

        if (t==NULL) 
        {
            return new_node(0);
        }

        if(t->val == k) {
           node* temp = new_node(0);
           temp->left=t->left;
           temp->right=t->right;

           temp->height = max(height(temp->left), height(temp->right)) +1;
           printf("%d TEMP\n", t->val);
           display(temp);
           return temp;    
       }
       if(k < t->val) {
           node* temp = split(t->left, k);
           temp->right = join(temp->right, t->right);
           temp->right = insert(temp->right, t->val);
           return temp;
       }
       if(k > t->val) {
           node* temp = split(t->right,k);
           printf("t->left\n");
           node* blah1, *blah2;
           blah1 = t->left;
           blah2 = temp->left;
           temp->left = join(blah1, blah2);
           temp->left = insert(temp->left, t->val);
           return temp;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should have `O(log (n)^2)` worst time complexity, since in the worst-case you'll be calling split `lg n` (i.e. on each depth) and your function takes `O(log n)` to call join at each depth, `log n * O(log n) = O(log (n)^2)`

Comment: I found this explanation https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.02120.pdf on pages 9 and 10. the algorithm is the same as mine and they say it is O(log(n)). I will be glad if you can check it and give me your opinion.

Comment: @MOUSAGANG You said that your `join` was `O(log n)` and `O(log(n)^2)` is the tightest upper bound we can get without knowing extra details about your join implementation.

Comment: What they have in the paper is in fact correct. However, `join` is `O(|log(n1) - log(n2)|)` not necessarily `O(log n)`. In our split algorithm, we know the difference between the height of the two trees can be bounded, so join is `O(1)` in our case and split is `O(log n)`.

Comment: maybe I have should made that clear, my Join function is O(log(n)) in the worst case. where n = n1+n2 is the number of elements of both AVL trees, but to be accurate it is O( | log(n1)-log(n2) | ).